# Qt: How to set topMargin of paragraph in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set a margin **above** the first paragraph of a `QTextEdit`. The problem is that it only shows up above the second paragraph; between the first and the second paragraph.

My current code is:

```
auto doc = ui->textEdit->document();
auto blockFormat = doc->begin().blockFormat();
blockFormat.setTopMargin(100);
QTextCursor{doc->begin()}.setBlockFormat(blockFormat);
```

Is this the intended behavior of QT? How would I achieve the desired outcome of having a margin above every paragraph, including the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be by design. A simple workaround would be to insert an empty paragraph, or a paragraph with a transparent 1x1 image.

Comment: thanks, i will have to lock the empty paragraph for editing, too. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567317/lock-a-line-in-qtextedit )